# Multiple VPN connections on one terminal server

Tags: vpn, terminal-server

Let's say I setup a terminal server and one user connects to it with several simultaneous rdp sessions from the same PC.

Could he setup different vpn profiles on each rdp session and have all of these going at once even though he is using one pc connecting to one terminal server?

Comment: Without having any additional details, my inclination is to say yes. Why wouldn't he be able to?

Comment: Just wondering if each one would show a different public IP or if there would be an issue.

Comment: TBH, this is fairly unanswerable without the details about the actual VPN. Is he connecting to the same VPN endpoint? Is he establishing each VPN connection with different credentials? Etc., etc.

Comment: @joeqwerty different VPN endpoints, different credentials

Comment: Then I'd say yes. TCP and UDP both use a 4-Tuple: Source Port|Source IP address<>Destination IP address|Destination Port. Each VPN connection is going to be unique as each one will originate from a different Source Port, even if the Source IP address is the same.